# urn contains 5 balls. 2 balls are drawn and are found to be white, Then prob. that all are white.

Tags: probability

An urn contains 5 balls. 2 balls are drawn and are found to be white. What is Probability that all balls are white

$\bf{My\; Try}::$ Let event $\bf{E_{1}=2}$ drawn balls are white.

Let event $\bf{E_{2}=3}$ drawn balls are white.

Let event $\bf{E_{3}=4}$ drawn balls are white.

Let event $\bf{E_{4}=5}$  drawn balls are white.

So Here $\displaystyle \bf{\bf{P(E_{1})} = \binom{5}{2}\;\;\;,P(E_{2})=\binom{5}{3}\;\;\;,P(E_{3})=\binom{5}{4}\;\;\;,P(E_{4})=\binom{5}{5}\;\;\;}$

I have seems that Here we have used Bayes Theorem, But I did not understand How can we ued it.

Please help me,

Thanks

Comment: My opinion is that the problem cannot be solved. We need a *prior* distribution. More informally, we need information on how the urn was filled with white/not-white balls.

Answer (score 1):

Given that there are $n$ white balls in the urn we can find the probability of drawing two white balls.

$P(2\ white\ balls\ chosen |n\ white\ balls\ in\ the\ urn) = \frac {n\choose 2}{5\choose 2}$

However you have been asked to find $P(n\ white\ balls\ in\ the\ urn|2\ white\ balls\ chosen )$

We can apply Bayes law.

$P(n|2) = P(2|n) \frac {P(n)}{P(2)}$

But there is still not enough information to answer the problem.

We have to think about how the urn was filled and get into the head of the urn filler.

Scenario 1:  When the urn was filled the urn filler rolled a die, and the die told him how many white balls to put into the urn.  In this case before you started drawing $0$ white balls in the urn was as likely as $5$ white balls in the urn.  After drawing 2, you know that there were not fewer than 2 white balls in the urn.

$P(5\ white\ balls\ in\ the\ urn|2\ chosen) =  \frac{1}{1+0.6+0.3+0.1}=\frac 12$

Scenario 2:  The urn filler was blindfolded and filled the urn from a pool ofa balls that was 50/50 white and colored.  2 colored balls in the urn is more likely than 0 colored balls in the urn.

$P(5\ white\ balls\ in\ the\ urn|2\ chosen) =  \frac{1}{1+3+3+1}=\frac 18$

Scenario 3:  The urn filler is a joker who always fills his urns with white balls.

$P(5\ white\ balls\ in\ the\ urn|2\ chosen) = 1$

And there are countless others.

Now you can take a weighted average based on the confidence you have in each of the assumptions, and arrive at your conclusion.

At this point there is no definitive right or wrong answer, as you are applying your own judgement.

Answer (score 0):

Since the two drawn are white, that means there were no more than 3 black balls in the original distribution. We have 2 choices for each ball color, so there are $2^5=32$ ways to assign the colors. But $\binom{5}{5}=1$ of those choices is all black and $\binom{5}{4}=5$ of those choices include exactly 4 black balls. Thus our sample space is reduced from 32 to 
$$
32 - \binom{5}{5} - \binom{5}{4} = 32 - 1 - 5 = 26.
$$
Thus the probability is $\dfrac{1}{26}$ that all 5 are white.

Comment: Nice. It should be noted that you are assuming that all initial configurations are supposed to be equally likely, which is not stated in the problem. Still it looks like a fair assumption, in order to get some reply. (also, there are no "black balls", but we may assume that to be synonym to "non-white balls" :)

Comment: I think there were some comments deleted that had other details, because I did make a lot of assumptions in my answer. But this was more than 3 years ago, so I am not sure anymore!

Comment: Thre.... oh! gee... I gotta look at the year in the dates :-) (Or, better, dates should be ISO, this style of dates are unreadable... "no one" places the year after the day)

Answer (score 0):

The *Universe of events* in this problem is partitioned into
the mutually exclusive, and totally exhaustive, events $A_k$
denoting the fact that the urn contains $k$ white balls
$$
U = A_{\,\,0}  \cup A_{\,\,1}  \cup  \cdots  \cup A_{\,\,5} 
$$

You don't specify the process by which the urns are filled-up
prior to the extraction, so we leave for the moment undefined.

Let $E_2$ denote the event "first two balls extracted are white".

Then given the urn $A_k$, with 5 balls of which $k$ white
the  number of ways to extract the first two balls white, will
be equal to the number of ways to extract $k-2$ white balls from the remaining $3$:
${{3} \choose {k-2}}$ over a total number of ways ${5 \choose k}$, i.e.:
$$
P\left( {E_{\,\,2} |A_{\,\,k} } \right) = \left( \matrix{
  3 \cr 
  k - 2 \cr}  \right)/\left( \matrix{
  5 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right) = \left[ {2 \le k} \right]{{3!k!} \over {\left( {k - 2} \right)!5!}} = k^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } /5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} }  = {{2!} \over {5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right)
$$
where  $x^{\,\underline {\,n\,} }$ denotes the *Falling Factorial*.

Then
$$
\eqalign{
  & P\left( {E_{\,\,2} } \right) = \sum\limits_k {P\left( {E_{\,\,2} |A_{\,\,k} } \right)P\left( {A_{\,\,k} } \right)}  = \sum\limits_k {P\left( {E_{\,\,2}  \cap A_{\,\,k} } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{2!} \over {5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,5} {\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right)P\left( {A_{\,\,k} } \right)}  = {1 \over {5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,5} {k^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } P\left( {A_{\,\,k} } \right)}  \cr} 
$$
and
$$
P\left( {E_{\,\,2}  \cap A_{\,\,k} } \right) = {{k^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } } \over {5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}P\left( {A_{\,\,k} } \right)
$$

Therefore we may conclude that
$$
P\left( {A_{\,\,k} |E_{\,\,2} } \right) = {{P\left( {A_{\,\,k}  \cap E_{\,\,2} } \right)} \over {P\left( {E_{\,\,2} } \right)}} =
 {{P\left( {E_{\,\,2}  \cap A_{\,\,k} } \right)} \over {P\left( {E_{\,\,2} } \right)}} =
 {{k^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } P\left( {A_{\,\,k} } \right)} \over {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,5} {k^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } P\left( {A_{\,\,k} } \right)} }}
$$

Let now do some assumptions regarding the probability of urn composition.

1) **all urns compositions equi-probable, with $P(A_{k})=1/6$**.

$$
P\left( {E_{\,\,2} } \right) = {{2!} \over {6\;5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,5} {\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right)}  = {{2!} \over {6\;5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}\left( \matrix{
  6 \cr 
  3 \cr}  \right) = {{2!} \over {3!}} = {1 \over 3}
$$
and
$$
\eqalign{
  & P\left( {A_{\,\,k} |E_{\,\,2} } \right) = {{k^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } P\left( {A_{\,\,k} } \right)} \over {5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } P\left( {E_{\,\,2} } \right)}} = {1 \over {2 \cdot \,5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}k^{\,\underline {\,2\,} }  = {1 \over {5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {0,\;0,\;{1 \over {20}},\;{3 \over {20}},\;{6 \over {20}},\;{{10} \over {20}}} \right] \cr} 
$$

2) **only urns with $2 \le k$  equi-probable, with $P(A_{k})=[2\le k] 1/4$**.

$$
P\left( {E_{\,\,2} } \right) = {2 \over {4\;5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}\sum\limits_{2\, \le \,k\, \le \,5} {\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right)}  = {1 \over 2}
$$
and we get the same result as above
$$
P\left( {A_{\,\,k} |E_{\,\,2} } \right) = {{k^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } P\left( {A_{\,\,k} } \right)} \over {5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } P\left( {E_{\,\,2} } \right)}} = \left[ {2 \le k} \right]{{k^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } } \over {2\;5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }} = {1 \over {5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right)
$$

3) **urns randomly filled with white/black balls, with $P(A_{k})={5 \choose k}/2^5$**.

$$
\eqalign{
  & P\left( {E_{\,\,2} } \right) = {1 \over {2^{\,5} \;5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,5} {k^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } \left( \matrix{
  5 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  = {1 \over {2^{\,4} \;5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,5} {\left( \matrix{
  5 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {2^{\,4} \;5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}\left( \matrix{
  5 \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right)\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,5} {\left( \matrix{
  3 \cr 
  k - 2 \cr}  \right)}  = {{2^{\,3} } \over {2^{\,4} \;5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}\left( \matrix{
  5 \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right) = {1 \over 4} \cr} 
$$
and
$$
\eqalign{
  & P\left( {A_{\,\,k} |E_{\,\,2} } \right) = {{k^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } } \over {2^{\,3} \;5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}\left( \matrix{
  5 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right) = {1 \over {2^{\,2} \;5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  5 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {2^{\,2} \;5^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}\left( \matrix{
  5 \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  3 \cr 
  k - 2 \cr}  \right) = {1 \over {2^{\,3} \;}}\left( \matrix{
  3 \cr 
  k - 2 \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {0,\;0,\;{1 \over 8},\;{3 \over 8},\;{3 \over 8},\;{1 \over 8}} \right] \cr} 
$$